# Pandas filter rows by substring within text column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a list of keywords as well as a DF that contains a text column. I am trying to filter out every row where the text in the text field contains one of the keywords. I believe what am I looking for is something like the `.isin` method but that would be able to take a regex argument as I am searching for substrings within the text not exact matches.

What I have:

```
keys = ['key','key2']

   A        Text
0  5   Sample text one
1  6   Sample text two 
2  3   Sample text three key
3  4   Sample text four key2
```

And I would like to remove any rows that contain a key in the text so I would end up with:

```
   A        Text
0  5   Sample text one
1  6   Sample text two
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) and join the keys using `|` to create a regex pattern and negate the boolean mask `~` to filter your df:

```
In [123]:
keys = ['key','key2']    ​
df[~df['Text'].str.contains('|'.join(keys))]

Out[123]:
   A              Text
0  5   Sample text one
1  6   Sample text two
```